# Warning while using strlen in C

Tags: c

I am new to C programming.I am trying to take input from a file line by line and print length of each line.
This is my code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
 {

    char name[100];
    printf("Enter file name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);



    FILE * input;
    input=fopen(name,"r");

    char line[100];
    fscanf(input,"%s",line);

    while(!feof(input))
    {

        printf("%d\n",strlen(line));
        fscanf(input,"%s",line);
    }


    return 0;
 }
```

This is my input file-

```
172.24.2.1
172.24.2.225
172.17.4.41
172.24.4.42
202.16.112.150
172.24.152.10
```

This  is `correctly` printing the length of each line.But during compilation I get this warning-

```
In function ‘main’:
main.c:24:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("%d\n",strlen(line));
```

So my question is why am I getting this warning although my output is correct and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21128092/1708801)

Comment: The easy answer is that the error message tells you exactly what's wrong - `(size_t != int)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `strlen` returns an object of type `size_t` (cf. ISO 9899:2011§7.24.6.3). You need to specify that the argument you pass to `printf` has type `size_t`, as opposed to `int`. You can do that by adding a `z` length modifier (cf. ISO 9899:2011§7.21.6.1/7) specifying an object of type `size_t`. You should also use the `u` formatting specifier as `size_t` is an unsigned type.

```
printf("%zu\n",strlen(line));
```

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, so the format specifier should be `%zu`. `%zd` is for signed types like `ssize_t`